# Cannot convert IFormfile to string

Tags: c#, .net-core, zip

I am trying to read a `zip file` with I get via `IFormFile` and I am going through the files inside to unzip a selected extension and unzip it but I cannot use the `IFormFile` to read it. It says cannot convert IFormFile to string.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(file))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
       if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".dbf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       {
         RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `IFormFile!=string`. I guess `OpenRead` expects a file. path

Comment: You cannot directly open an `IFormFile`, you need to copy to a `Steam` instance of some type, and then open that to look at the content.

Comment: Thanks @bolkay . Yes, OpenRead does expect a file path so that did the trick. How can I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: @Novica Josifovski I have added an answer. You can only approve an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `IFormFile != string`. I guess `OpenRead` expects a file path.

So, first read the content of the `IFormFile` into a file, then use that file path.

Answer (score 1):

Although this won't help in this particular case (since ZipFile.OpenRead() expects a file), for those coming here after googling "iformfile to string", you can read an IFormFile into a string, for example as follows:-

```
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(iFormFile.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            result.AppendLine(reader.ReadLine());
        }
    }
```